# binding multi dropdown list in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have a multi dropdown list and I need to do the following:
1. Make sure that when selecting value in one dropdown list it won't appear in the others (couldn't find a proper solution here).
2. When selecting the value "Text" a text field (`<input>`) will apear instead of the Yes/no dropdown.
3. "Choose option" will appear only for the first row (still working on it).
4. Make sure that if "Text" is selected, it always will be on the top (still working on it).

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adNuR/4759/)

**HTML**:

```
  <div class='liveExample'> 
   <table width='100%'>
                <tbody data-bind='foreach: lines'>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Choose option:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select data-bind='options: filters, optionsText: "name", value: filterValue'> </select>
                        </td>
                        <td data-bind="with: filterValue">
                            <select data-bind='options: filterValues, optionsText: "name", value: "name"'> </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button href='#' data-bind='click: $parent.removeFilter'>Remove</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <button data-bind='click: addFilter'>Add Choice</button>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**:

```
var CartLine = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.filter = ko.observable();
    self.filterValue = ko.observable();

    // Whenever the filter changes, reset the value selection
    self.filter.subscribe(function() {
        self.filterValue(undefined);
    });
};

var Cart = function() {
    // Stores an array of filters
    var self = this;
    self.lines = ko.observableArray([new CartLine()]); // Put one line in by default

    // Operations
    self.addFilter = function() { self.lines.push(new CartLine()) };
    self.removeFilter = function(line) { self.lines.remove(line) };
};


ko.applyBindings(new Cart());
```

I will appeaciate your assist here! Mainly for the first problem.

Thanks!
Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to limit the options based on the options that are already selected in the UI, you'll need to make sure every `cartLine` gets its own array of filters. Let's pass it in the constructor like so:

```
var CartLine = function(availableFilters) {
  var self = this;
  self.availableFilters = availableFilters;

  // Other code
  // ...
};
```

You'll have to use this new viewmodel property instead of your global `filters` array:

```
<td>
  <select data-bind='options: availableFilters, 
    optionsText: "name", 
    value: filterValue'> </select>
</td>
```

Now, we'll have to find out which filters are still available when creating a new `cartLine` instance. `Cart` manages all the `lines`, and has an `addFilter` function.

```
self.addFilter = function() {
  var availableFilters = filters.filter(function(filter) {
    return !self.lines().some(function(cartLine) {
      var currentFilterValue = cartLine.filterValue();
      return currentFilterValue &&
        currentFilterValue.name === filter.name;
    });
  });

  self.lines.push(new CartLine(availableFilters))
};
```

The new `CartLine` instance gets only the filter that aren't yet used in any other line. (Note: if you want to use `Array.prototype.some` in older browsers, you might need a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some))

The only thing that remains is more of an UX decision than a "coding decision": do you want users to be able to change previous "Choices" after having added a new one? If this is the case, you'll need to create computed `availableFilters` arrays rather than ordinary ones.

Here's a forked fiddle that contains the code I posted above: http://jsfiddle.net/ztwcqL69/ Note that you can create doubled choices, because choices remain editable after adding new ones. If you comment what the desired behavior would be, I can help you figure out how to do so. This might require some more drastic changes... The solution I provided is more of a pointer in the right direction.

**Edit: I felt bad for not offering a *final* solution, so here's another approach:**

If you want to update the `availableFilters` retrospectively, you can do so like this:

`CartLine`s get a reference to their `siblings` (the other cart lines) and create a subscription to any changes via a `ko.computed` that uses `siblings` *and* their `filterValue`:

```
var CartLine = function(siblings) {
  var self = this;

  self.availableFilters = ko.computed(function() {
    return filters.filter(function(filter) {
      return !siblings()
        .filter(function(cartLine) { return cartLine !== self })
        .some(function(cartLine) {
        var currentFilterValue = cartLine.filterValue();
        return currentFilterValue &&
          currentFilterValue.name === filter.name;
      });
    });
  });

  // Other code...
};
```

Create new cart lines like so: `self.lines.push(new CartLine(self.lines))`. Initiate with an empty array and push the first `CartLine` afterwards by using `addFilter`.

*Concerning point 2:* You can create a computed observable that sorts based on filterValue:

```
self.sortedLines = ko.computed(function() {

  return self.lines().sort(function(lineA, lineB) {
    if (lineA.filterValue() && lineA.filterValue().name === "Text") return -1;
    if (lineB.filterValue() && lineB.filterValue().name === "Text") return 1;

    return 0;
  });

});
```

*Point 3*: Move it outside the `foreach`.

*Point 4*: Use an `if` binding:

```
<td data-bind="with: filterValue">
  <!-- ko if: name === "Text" -->
  <input type="text">
  <!-- /ko -->
  <!-- ko ifnot: name === "Text" -->
  <select data-bind='options: filterValues, optionsText: "name", value: "name"'> </select>          
   <!-- /ko -->
<td>
```

Updated fiddle that contains this code: http://jsfiddle.net/z22m1798/

Comment: Thanks you for directing me! it seems to be helpful. However I notice that there are 3 issues: 1) when clicking on 'add', the new dropdown contains 'Text' although it is selected in the first dropdown. 2) when removing dropdown, the selected value doesn't added to other dropdowns. 3) When selecting value, it doesn't remove it from other dropdowns (just from the new ones that will be added). Thanks

Comment: Wow, Thanks! Your edit seems to solve my MAIN problem :-)

Comment: I've updated my answer to offer a more complete solution rather than just a pointer in the right direction... Let me know if I described it clearly. Note that passing a `Cart` property to `CartLine` isn't the cleanest pattern to use. You'll have to be careful not to mutate it and only use it to subscribe to changes. You might want to refactor this to a single `subscribe` inside `Cart` that updates all its `lines` actively.

Comment: I've answered your other questions as well and have now created the longest answer in my short stackoverflow history... One last remark: answering these last questions kind of felt like I was doing your work for you and you hadn't really tried yet. Try to explain what you tried and didn't work next time.

Comment: You are completely right about your comment about the last question - I should have try harder! I leared a lot from you answers. Point3: moving it outside of `foreach` won't help here because it will appear on the top and in addition I have to take care of cases of removing the first line. I will find the solution for that and implement your direction for point4 as well. Thanks a lot for you help!

Comment: Point3: In order to add the text only in the first line I added `<span data-bind='text:"Choose option:",visible: (\$index() === 0) ' ></span>`. Point4: the "Text" isn't on the top. The sorting function looks good but I found that when clicking on 'Add' the new value isn't in the lines array so it not part of the sorting. Only when changing the value, it is sorted as expected. I unable to figure out why it isn't part of the array right after clicking on 'Add' (I tried to compare it to other working examples but still can't find out why). I am very sorry but the this logic is new for me.

Comment: The browser shows the first select option as the default selection, but it doesn't trigger a change event. Therefore, `filterValue` is undefined when you create a new line. You could mimic the browser's behavior by initializing `filterValue` like so: `self.filterValue = ko.observable(self.availableFilters()[0]);`

Comment: Thanks a lot for you kind assist and explanations!